# Do requests for UK home office passenger subject data get recorded with the rest of the data?

Tags: visas, uk

Could the fact and circumstances of such a request conceivably be used against you in any border/visa related determinations in the future?

Comment: Be aware that a Subject Access Request does not give you everything that UK immigration has on record - they specifically and deliberately withhold information that they think a subject could use to commit immigration fraud.

Comment: Solely from a processing of SAR applications point of view, it would seem sensible to assume that a record of the request and the reply given will be held on file. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration Since the information provided is personal information about you already held in the Home Office’s immigration records, which you have a legal right to request, it’s hard to see how making such a request could be used against you. Do you have a particular concern in mind?

Comment: @Moo, could you be more clear/specific? And also, could you please indicate your source for this? Thanks

Comment: @Traveller, basically, I was refused entry once, which I presume was recorded, and then I entered successfully on the advice of the British embassy through a ferry from Ireland without realizing the period for visa free entry was limited, so it now seems as though I've overstayed by 2.5 years. I want to take up a study course and figure out what marks they have on record against me in applying for a UK student visa.

Comment: @JosephP. ‘Seems’ or ‘did’ overstay? Your entry refusal will be on record. If you entered subsequently and overstayed, they’ll have it on file and/or you’ll have to declare the length of stay in the application anyway. Either way, the mere request for a SAR win’t be a red flag, it’s just a factual report of what they already know about your immigration history. The timeframe for getting a reply might be (much) longer than usual, government departments in the UK are not operating normally due to Covid